# How to use open ssh key?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I got a ssh key in ppk format. I found some manual to convert it to an open ssh key. Now I just want to connect to the server using this key. The manuals I find are all about creating one. Do I have to put the key in the .ssh folder? Or can I include the file in a ssh command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP already has a key, it is a .ppk which is a format used by Putty. The OP has converted it to an open ssh key already.

To use the key,

First, by default, the key should stored in ~/.ssh with permissions of 600 as outlined above.

Second, you have two options to use the key.

Option 1 - Use putty - You can install and use putty in Linux. Putty can use the key in either format.

Option 2 - Use ssh on the command line

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_key user@server
```

If you have any errors , post them here.

If you like, I posted some information on ssh keys from a LUG meeting here - http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_keys

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate a public key out of the private key you have there (if you don't have it yet) and determine the key type:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -y -f /path/to/private/keyfile
   ```

   This will output something like `ssh-rsa AAA[...]` (for RSA type) or `ssh-dsa AAA[...]` (for DSA type).
2. Put the private key as a file in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (if RSA type) or `~/.ssh/id_dsa` (if DSA)
3. Put the public key in place - essentially the same as in the first step, but redirecting the output.

   ```
   ssh-keygen -y -f /path/to/private/keyfile > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```

   Replace `rsa` with `dsa` if needed.
4. Fix the permissions (optional, SSH client may complain if not set appropriately):

   ```
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   chmod 700 ~/.ssh
   ```

   Again, replace `rsa` with `dsa` if needed.

The `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` paths are default locations where the OpenSSH client looks for keys. You can set your own location, though, by setting this in your client configuration file, e.g. in `~/.ssh/config`.

```
Host *
IdentityFile /path/to/myprivatekey
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a pair of keys: a private and a public key. You need to put your *public* key in the `authorized_keys` file in the `.ssh/` folder on the server to which you wish to connect. This public key will then be used during the authentication process to challenge your private key that you must keep in the `.ssh/` directory of the computer which is your client (from which you are connecting to the server).

You will, without a doubt, run into troubles. Use the command `ssh -v -v -v` (yes, verbose option repeated several times increases verbosity) to understand what is going on during the authentication.